# how to render a component by string name

Tags: arrays, string, reactjs, components, react-fiber

I seem to be unable to render components using name strings. I wanted to be able to dynamically generate component name strings which have existing corresponding components that can be rendered.

The `array` const is going to be populated via JSON data, that's why I need to use `string` values for identifying the component.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
import Module1 from './module1';
import Module2 from './module2';
import Module3 from './module3';

const array = ['Module1', 'Module2', 'Module3'];

{array.map((Module, index) =>
 <Module />
)}
```

Instead of referencing the existing component and rendering it, React is rendering a custom element tag that is all lower case.

NOTE: those components `['Module1', 'Module2', 'Module3']` are created as `extends Component`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the components in an object and access them using the strings as keys.

```
import Module1 from './module1';
import Module2 from './module2';
import Module3 from './module3';

const array = ['Module1', 'Module2', 'Module3'];

const modules = {
  Module1,
  Module2,
  Module3,
};

{moduleOrderArr.map((key, index) => {
  const Module = modules[key];
  return <Module />;
})}
```

Comment: but, I will not know the component name. how can this part `const modules = {
  Module1,
  Module2,
  Module3,
};`

can be dynamic?

Comment: You can just put every component you import into the object. You can also set the keys to something other than the names of the components.

Comment: ah! great idea. Thanks