# Sequence components based on order specified in array of strings in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of string that specifies the order in which my components are rendered.

```
const requiredOrder = [ "Line1Component", "Line3Component", "Line2Component" ];
```

I also have components with names that match the string in my above array.

**I want to render the components based on the order mentioned in my requiredOrder array.**

When I try to run the below code, I get:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {OrderredComponents}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Minified: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

I tried to wrap the return statement in a wrapper, but still not able to figure out what's wrong.

I want to avoid case statements as mentioned here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195446/rendering-react-components-in-a-specified-order) as my requiredOrder list may grow very big.

```js
class OrderMyComponents extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const requiredOrder = [
      "Line1Component",
      "Line2Component",
      "Line3Component"
    ];

    const Line1Component = () => (
      <div>
        <b>Line 1</b>
      </div>
    );
    const Line2Component = () => (
      <div>
        <b>Line 2</b>
      </div>
    );
    const Line3Component = () => (
      <div>
        <b>Line 3</b>
      </div>
    );

    const OrderredComponents = requiredOrder.map(function(item) {
      return { item };
    });

    return <OrderredComponents />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <OrderMyComponents />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717326/how-to-render-a-component-by-string-name Here is a question similar to this one.

Comment: That doesn't help as I would need to do that mapping of my key from requiredOrder and the corresponding component. Thats the challenge to do that dynamically.

I cannot do that as I get the requiredOrder as an input for my component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an object with a component name as a key as per https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/dynamic-tag-names-in-react-and-jsx-17e366a684e9

and that solved my problem.

Thanks [agent_hunt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4826200/agent-hunt) and [thakur-karthik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7364894/thakur-karthik) for your help.

```js
const components = {
  Line1Component: () => (
    <div>
      <b>Line 2</b>
    </div>
  ),
  Line2Component: () => (
    <div>
      <b>Line 2</b>
    </div>
  ),
  Line3Component: () => (
    <div>
      <b>Line 3</b>
    </div>
  )
};

class OrderMyComponents extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const requiredOrder = [
      "Line1Component",
      "Line2Component",
      "Line3Component"
    ];

    return requiredOrder.map((item, key) => {
      const Component = components[item];

      return <Component />;
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <OrderMyComponents />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual use case is if you want to render the dynamic data i.e the list of strings. You can just use one component and render those. Example

```js
class OrderMyComponents extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const requiredOrder = [
      "Line1Component",
      "Line2Component",
      "Line3Component"
    ];

    const ItemComponent = (item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <b>{item}</b>
      </div>
    );
    

    return <div>{requiredOrder.map(ItemComponent)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <OrderMyComponents />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

But if you want to lookup a different component for each item in your array, you can refer to this [how to render a component by string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717326/how-to-render-a-component-by-string-name) as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7364894/thakur-karthik

```js
class OrderMyComponents extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const requiredOrder = [
      <div key={1}>
        <b>Line1Component</b>
      </div>,
      <div key={2}>
        <b>Line2Component</b>
      </div>,
      <div key={3}>
        <b>Line3Component</b>
      </div>
   ];

    

    return <div>{requiredOrder}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <OrderMyComponents />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: That doesn't help as I would need to do that mapping of my key from requiredOrder and the corresponding component. Thats the challenge to do that dynamically.

I cannot do that as I get the requiredOrder as an input for my component.

Comment: You could actually create an array of components as well instead specifying an order and looking up separately . It would help if could explain a bit more context of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am trying to create the same - array of components as you mentioned. Context is: I want to build an i18n address component for entering international addresses. This component receives a list of address fields in particular country. Different countries have different order of address fields. Fields are - addressline1,2,3postalcode, locality, country. Based on the list received, I have to order my component. My component receives a sequence as input. I have render the components in that order.